# Update UIView size based on parent size using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I have a view `PView` and its subview `SView` added by setting height and width constraints programmatically.

Now, at some point of time I want to update the `SView`'s constraints based on `PView`'s width. But there is no direct relation between the two. I need to perform some calculation using the `PView`'s size and then set `SView`'s width and height constraints from the result.

And need to set the constraints in the `updateConstraints` method of `PView`.
I accessed the `PView`'s size in the `updateConstraints` method but sometimes that comes as old value because `updateConstraints` is executed bottom-up.

Any hints how it can be done?

Comment: Why can't you just assign size to size in your constraints?

Comment: Didn't get you said. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Would you be able to show us some of your code and some example images of what you want to achieve?

Comment: yes, please, some of your code.

Comment: show us what you want to achieve and then we can guide